# Can't change custom class of UIButton to GIDSignInButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, interface-builder, google-signin

I'm trying to add Google sign in functionality to a custom button, and I'm following [this](https://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/) tutorial. It's telling me to select the button, and set its class as `GIDSignInButton`, then add this code: `@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!`.

However, it doesn't let me set the class to `GIDSignInButton`. When I type it in and press enter, the field just clears.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you added the library correctly to your project? Can you use the functions/types of the library from your code?

Comment: Yes, I can use the functions. And strangely the authentication is working perfectly, even without changing the button's class for some reason.

Comment: Is it showing an option to change the `Module` option below `Class` option ?

Comment: No, `Module` is greyed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **workaround** is open the `storyboard` in **text mode** and put it directly. When you return to the `interface builder` it will show normally.

Comment: This worked, thanks! However it ended up changing the styling of my button so I've left it out for now. It works perfectly without it.

Answer (score 15):

You should try assign GIDSignInButton not to the Button Object from the Object library but to the the View Object instead

It's work for me.

It will look like this using UIView instead of UIButton.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can create UIButton and then on its action method you can write this code for signing via google:

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

It works for me, in this way you can customize UIButton according to your requirement and also perform signin by using google

Answer (score 12):

That's because GIDSignInButton is a subclass of UIView, not UIButton.
Add to the storyboard / nib a regular UIView and change it's class to GIDSignInButton instead.

From [google doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in_button):

> Add a GIDSignInButton to your storyboard, XIB file, or instantiate it
>   programmatically. To add the button to your storyboard or XIB file,
>   add a **View** and set its custom class to GIDSignInButton.

Answer (score 6):

GIDSignInButton can be set by using a `UIView` or a `UIButton`.

**If you are using `GIDSignInButton` as a UIButton**

1. open the storyboard as source code
2. Find the button in resulting `XML`
3. Add the below code  as an attribute for the button tag

   `customClass="GIDSignInButton"`

4.open `storyboard` again as Interface Builder, button class will be changed

> If you are using GIDSignInButton as a UIView

1.copy paste the custom class as `GIDSignInButton` in `Identity Inspector`
The second one is the correct approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open storyboard as source code.
2. Locate the button in the xml.
3. Set customClass="GIDSignInButton" as an attribute for the button tag.
4. Open storyboard as interface builder.

You can now link the button to the IBOutlet

Answer (score 2):

If you use a UIView instead of a UIButton, you can assign the view a custom class of GIDSignInButton. From there you can connect the view to a button outlet and action as seen below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var googleLoginButton: GIDSignInButton!

  @IBAction func googleLoginButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few months ago,

Your code seems to be right

```
@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
```

But, the problem might be

• You haven’t added the Framework properly 
(Go to your project setting in the left side navigator, and click Build phases, add your framework and SHIFT + CMD + K)

• Or alternatively, go ahead and write the @IBOutlet in your swift file, then drag the button to assign it

• your last option is to close xcode, or maybe delete the derived data

Xcode itself has plenty of bugs, I am not sure if it’s your problem, it’s xcode’s

Hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't work :/ Probably an Xcode bug then, thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: No, thank you.. let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do is just make a button action and paste the following lines in it.

```
   @IBAction func gSignInAction(_ sender: Any) {
         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **UIView** instead of **UIButton** and assign custom class as **GIDSignInButton**

Answer (score 0):

Swift- 5

```
Open storyboard as source code.
Locate the button in the xml.
Set customClass="GIDSignInButton" as an attribute for the button tag.
Open storyboard as interface builder.

//MARK:- You will not find this with button XML Forcly Add this (customClass="GIDSignInButton")[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```