# Email/Password Button Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'll speak briefly because my English is terrible.

I am trying to create this button

[image]

I already tried google guide but is outdated and is not clear how the button is created.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase has very good documentation for every platform, how to implement authentication for Gmail button.

You can go to following links for different platforms:

1. IOS (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui)
2. Android (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui)
3. Web (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web)

If you can give me more detail about your problem. I might guide you properly.

Comment: Is there any way to do as the google sign in ? create a view and use the class GIDSignInButton(for the email would be another class).

Comment: If you use a UIView instead of a UIButton, you can assign the view a custom class of GIDSignInButton. From there you can connect the view to a button outlet and action as seen below.
`` 
@IBOutlet weak var googleLoginButton: GIDSignInButton!

  @IBAction func googleLoginButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
}
``
You can also get idea from other stackoverflow answer also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960149/cant-change-custom-class-of-uibutton-to-gidsigninbutton

Comment: Yeah but i am trying to do with the email i already have the google one

Comment: No, I don't think so.